# if function does not exist write function - javascript

Tags: javascript, function, typeof

In php I'm writing the following

```
<?php
if(x != 0) {
echo "function myfunction(){};";    
}
?>
```

In javascript I wish to test if the function exists and if not write out an empty function

```
if(typeof myfunction != 'function'){
    function myfunction(){};
}
```

This works great in firefox but, in chrome even if the typeof equals function it still goes into and creates the empty function.  I can't find a work around for chrome, i've tried if(!myfunction), if(typeof window.myfunction != 'function) but nothing seems to work here for chrome when everything seems to work in firefox.  Any ideas?

Comment: Still no answer? I have the same problem and the solution below doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use a function expression, not a function declaration.

```
if(typeof myfunction != 'function'){
   window.myfunction = function(){};
}
```

(I'm using `window` since your last paragraph suggests you want a global function)

Answer (score 6):

You should use strict comparison operator !==

```
if(typeof myFunction !== 'function'){
    window.myFunction = function(){}; // for a global function or
    NAMESPACE.myFunction = function(){}; // for a function in NAMESPACE 
}
```

Also try to keep js functions inside namespaces, this way you avoid collisions with other js libraries in the future.