# Declare such Function if it does not exist

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [if function does not exist write function - javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839112/if-function-does-not-exist-write-function-javascript)

I have a situation when some function X is being called. After some postbacks this function is no longer declared, but still being called by  the code, obviously i get js error saying `X is not defined` . (call it a bug if you wish) but
It is not under my control to not call it or to change the calling functionality.

What I would like to do is a fail safe that will declare such function if it does not exist. So the logic is:

If function not declared then declare one.

Is that possible in javascript i.e. to declare/register a function dynamically in global scope?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if (typeof window.functionX === 'undefined') {
    window.functionX = function() {
      // fallback code here
    }
}
```

Comment: this answer is more suitable for front end only, for bot BE and FE js 

"if(!myFunc) {
 var myFunc = function() {}
}"
is a compatible solution

Answer (score 4):

Sure it is

```
if(!myFunc) {
  myFunc = function() {}
}
```